# Unsupervised classification using ISODATA clustering in R

Tags: r, classification, clustering

Is there a way (e.g. package) to perform an unsupervised classification using the ISODATA clustering algorithm in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that closest you are going to come is the unsuperClass function in the RStoolbox package (http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/unsuperClass.html). This function implements a k-means and not ISOCLUSER but, it is an unsupervised approach that is, honestly, preferable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why is this approach preferable?

Comment: K-Means provides flexibility in defining class centers as well as evaluating the margin function (silhouettes) to find supported k (number of clusters).

Answer (score 2):

There is a GitHub page on [ISODATA clustering in R](https://github.com/johnbaums/cluster) that may be worth a check.

[image]